# Spring MVC and JSR 303 custom validation with custom resource bundle

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation

I know this has been asked thousands of times, but this really is a nightmare. I've been trying to figure out for days how to configure Hibernate Validator to use my property resource bundle and I still cannot get a satisfying result...

Here is a part of my web context:

```
    <!-- i18n handling -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="i18n.eSporx" />
    </bean>
```

Here is a part of my application context:

```
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
            <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
```

And finally, my (class-level cross-field) custom constraint and its validator:

```
@Documented
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CrossDateConstraintsValidator.class)
public @interface CrossDateConstraints {

    String message() default "crossdate.validation.error";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String startDateFieldName() default "startDate";

    String endDateFieldName() default "endDate";
}


@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CrossDateConstraintsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CrossDateConstraints, Object> {

    private String startDateField;
    private String endDateField;
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final CrossDateConstraints constraintAnnotation) {
        startDateField = constraintAnnotation.startDateFieldName();
        endDateField = constraintAnnotation.endDateFieldName();
        message = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object annotatedClassInstance, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            Date startDate = getDateFieldValue(annotatedClassInstance, startDateField);
            Date endDate = getDateFieldValue(annotatedClassInstance, endDateField);
            isValid = endDate.after(startDate);

            if (!isValid) {
                forceErrorsOnBothFields(context);
            }

            return isValid;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return isValid;
        }
    }

    private void forceErrorsOnBothFields(final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message).addNode(startDateField).addConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message).addNode(endDateField).addConstraintViolation();
    }

    private Date getDateFieldValue(final Object annotatedClassInstance, final String fieldName) throws IntrospectionException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Method dateGetter = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName, annotatedClassInstance.getClass()).getReadMethod();
        Date date = (Date) dateGetter.invoke(annotatedClassInstance);
        return date;
    }
}
```

The resource bundle is located under `src/main/resources/i18n/eSporx.properties` (with its locale variants). Such things as `<spring:message code="my.key" />` in my JSPs work fine. However, whenever a CrossDateConstraints error is raised, all I can read is "crossdate.validation.error" even if the key is stored in the properties file!

If you have an idea, please tell me :)
This is so frustrating.

Rolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of `hibernate-validator` don't allow to override the default resource bundle. Please ensure that you use a recent version like the `4.2.0.Final`.

That say, even if you already use a recent version, this version can be overrided by the one embedded in your application server. Glassfish 3.0 for instance, embeds a version of `hibernate-validator` that doesn't support the resource bundle override.

Comment: Upgrade to 4.2.0.Final and try again.

Answer (score 1):

To enable message's interpolation you must surround message by braces, like this:

```
String message() default "{crossdate.validation.error}";
```

See also [2.2.4. Message interpolation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation) chapter in Hibernate Validator guide.